# Gitlab Pipeline to install Ansible Galaxy role fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a functional gitlab pipeline to publish code to AWS server. It suddenly started failing without any reason. I am getting following error. Can someone give me some clue? I cannot post the whole code as it is very lengthy.

```
** [WARNING]: - geerlingguy.docker was NOT installed successfully: missing
required 'current_version' from server response
(https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/)
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**
```

Comment: Seeing the same in my pipeline today.

Comment: Did you get a change to resolve ?

Answer (score 7):

The Ansible team released a new Galaxy server.
You'd need to use Ansible >=2.13.9 to download content from it.

In case you are using an older version, there is a new url to use to get packages : https://old-galaxy.ansible.com/

Here is what to put in your ansible.cfg file :

```
[galaxy]
server = https://old-galaxy.ansible.com/
```

Comment: I dont find this file or url in the project. Can you please suggest me, where should I check ? I am using AWS ec2 ubuntu instance.

Comment: Maybe you can't find it because it doesn't exist.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/examples/ansible.cfg

Here is how it looks like, I'd advise only overriding what you really need, such as the galaxy url server.

Comment: I tried to create a file and overide it. But still it dont work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like below

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml --server="https://old-galaxy.ansible.com" --ignore-certs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like following.
Update file "requirements.yaml" with source website name.

example :

collections:

- name: community.general

  version: 4.2.0

  source: https://old-galaxy.ansible.com/